# Jenkins issue with maven install

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins as well as maven. I am trying to build my project using jenkins job. I am getting the following error

```
Building remotely on s10-slave in workspace /cstg/jenkins/workspace/SAPlatform-CSPC_greenfield
Updating https://savi-svn/svn/analytics_visualization/ServiceAnalytics/Applications/CSPC/trunks/Listener/CSPC_greenfield at revision '2015-08-05T21:24:42.598 -0500'
D         pom.xml
A         pom.xml

At revision 22510
no revision recorded for https://savi-svn/svn/analytics_visualization/ServiceAnalytics/Applications/CSPC/trunks/Listener/CSPC_greenfield in the previous build

Parsing POMs

Failed to transfer Could not find artifact CSPC:CSPC:pom:1.1 in NLS proxy central jboss ibiblio codehaus java.net (http://engci-maven.cisco.com/artifactory/cstg-smartservices-group/)

Failed to transfer Could not find artifact CSPC:CSPC:pom:1.1 in maven-proxy (http://engci-maven-master.cisco.com/artifactory/cisco-central-repo)


 Failed to transfer Could not find artifact CSPC:CSPC:pom:1.1 in savi.group.scas.snapshot (http://caisisapp-dev1-16:8081/nexus/content/groups/savi.group.scas.snapshot/)
Failed to transfer Could not find artifact CSPC:CSPC:pom:1.1 in intellishield.group.snapshots (http://caisisapp-dev1-



<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>CSPC</groupId>
    <artifactId>CSPC</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>CSPC_greenfield</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>CSPC_greenfield Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cisco.ca.ast.ir.sodcSvcs</groupId>
        <artifactId>SodcUtils</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.27</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tibco.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>tibjms</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tibco.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>tibcrypt</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
        <version>11.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>connectivityexternal</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmslistener-util</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.tibco.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>tibcrypt</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.tibco.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>tibjms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>savi.group.snapshot</id>
        <url>http://caisisapp-dev1-16:8081/nexus/content/groups/savi.connectivity.group.snapshot</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>savi.group.release</id>
        <url>http://caisisapp-dev1-16:8081/nexus/content/groups/savi.group.release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>cstg-smartservices-group</id>
        <url>http://engci-maven.cisco.com/artifactory/cstg-smartservices-group/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>cstg-smartservices-release</id>
        <url>http://engci-maven.cisco.com/artifactory/cstg-smartservices-release/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>cstg-smartservices-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://engci-maven.cisco.com/artifactory/cstg-smartservices-snapshots</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>cstg-smartservices-thirdparty</id>
        <url>http://engci-maven.cisco.com/artifactory/cstg-smartservices-thirdparty</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>sstg-nls</id>
        <url>http://maven.cisco.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/sstg-nls/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>sstg-nls-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://maven.cisco.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/sstg-nls-snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>sstg-nls-thirdparty</id>
        <url>http://maven.cisco.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/sstg-nls-thirdparty/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>sstg-nls-group</id>
        <url>http://maven.cisco.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/sstg-nls-group/</url>
    </repository>
    <!-- <repository> <id>savi.group.snapshot</id> <url> http://caisisapp-dev1-16:8081/nexus/content/repositories/savi.connectivity.repo.release 
        </url> </repository> <repository> <id>sstg-nls</id> <url>http://maven.cisco.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/sstg-nls/</url> 
        </repository> <repository> <id>sstg-nls-snapshots</id> <url>http://maven.cisco.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/sstg-nls-snapshots/</url> 
        </repository> -->
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>savi.group.snapshot</id>
        <url>http://caisisapp-dev1-16:8081/nexus/content/groups/savi.connectivity.group.snapshot</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>savi.group.release</id>
        <url>http://caisisapp-dev1-16:8081/nexus/content/groups/savi.group.release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<build>
    <finalName>CSPC_greenfield</finalName>
</build>
```

please find the pom.xml. Let me know what am i missing here.

Tried:

- changing the version of the pom.xml from 1.0 to 1.1
- changed the artifactID name

Command used:

clean install -s "/home/jenkins/.m2/sa-settings.xml"

Comment: This is in your local environment or in company ?

Answer (score 0):

maven is telling you that the parent pom can't no be found.

This project is a children of a parent project, you should find the parent pom (usually is in the parent folder) and verify that the artifactid, groupId and version are the same.